# In R Shiny, how to dynamically expand the use of a function as user inputs expand?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, shiny

The following MWE code interpolates user inputs (Y values in 2-column matrix input grid in sidebar panel, id = `input1`) over X periods (per slider input in sidebar, id = `periods`). The custom interpolation function `interpol()` is triggered in server section by `results <- function(){interpol(...)}`. User has the option to add or modify scenarios by clicking on the single action button, which triggers a modal housing a 2nd expandable matrix input (id = `input2`). Interpolation results are presented in the plot in the main panel. So far so good, works as intended.

As drafted, the `results` function only processes the first matrix input including any modifications to it executed in the 2nd matrix input.

My question: how do I expand the `results` function to include scenarios > 1 added in the 2nd expandable matrix input, and automatically include them in the output plot? I've been wrestling with a for-loop to do this but don't quite know how. I've avoided for-loops, instead relying on lapply and related. But in practice a user will not input more than 20-30 scenarios max and perhaps a for-loop is a harmless option. But I'm open to any solution and am certainly not wedded to a for-loop!

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

interpol <- function(a,b){ # a = periods, b = matrix inputs
  c <- rep(NA,a)
  c[1] <- b[1]
  c[a] <- b[2]
  c <- approx(seq_along(c)[!is.na(c)],c[!is.na(c)],seq_along(c))$y # this interpolates
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(uiOutput("panel"),actionButton("showInput2","Modify/add interpolation")),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  results <- function(){interpol(req(input$periods),req(input$input1))}
  
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput('periods','Interpolate over periods (X):',min=2,max=12,value=6),
      uiOutput("input1"))
  })

  output$input1 <- renderUI({
    matrixInput("input1", 
                label = "Interpolation 1 (Y values):",
                value =  matrix(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){c(input$input2[1],input$input2[2])} 
                                  else {c(1,5)},                        # matrix values
                                1, 2,                                   # matrix row/column count
                                dimnames = list(NULL,c("Start","End"))  # matrix column header
                                ),
                rows =  list(names = FALSE),
                class = "numeric")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showInput2,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        matrixInput("input2",
          label = "Automatically numbered scenarios (input into blank cells to add):",
          value = if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2}
                  else if(isTruthy(input$input1)){input$input1},
          rows =  list(names = FALSE),
          cols =  list(extend = TRUE,
                       delta = 2,
                       delete = TRUE,
                       multiheader=TRUE),
          class = "numeric"),
    footer = modalButton("Close")
    ))
  })

  observe({
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- paste(trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1, " (start|end)")
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(results())
    plot(results(),type="l", xlab = "Periods (X)", ylab = "Interpolated Y values")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user can (presumably) add only one scenario at a time, I don't think a `for` loop is going to help.  The way I handle situations like this is to bind additional data to the appropriate reactive in an `observeEvent`.  This will then trigger updates in the necessary outputs automatically.  Here's a MWE to illustrate the technique.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add scenario"),
  plotOutput("plot"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(results=tibble(Scenario=1, X=1:10, Y=runif(10)))
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    newData <- tibble(Scenario=max(v$results$Scenario) + 1, X=1:10, Y=runif(10))
    v$results <- v$results %>% bind_rows(newData)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    v$results %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=as.factor(Scenario)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```